# Como realizar una consiulta SQL con condicional OR y atributos no nulos en ruby on rails

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, ruby-on-rails, ruby, console

Estoy tratando de realizar una consulta:

```
Select * from Packages where children_price is not null or children_price is not null;
```

Estas consultas funcionan perfectamente:

```
p = Package.where.not(children_price: nil)
p = Package.where.not(children_foreigner_price: nil)
```

El problema surge cuando intento unirlas:

```
np = Package.where.not(children_price: nil).or(Package.where.not(children_foreigner_price: nil))
```

Eso no funciona:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

también he intentado lo siguiente:

```
np = Package.where.not(["children_price = :cp or children_foreigner_price = :cfp", {cp: nil, cfp: nil}])
```

Y esto tampoco me funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien que pueda ayudarme con esa consulta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

np = Package.where(["children_price is not :cp or children_foreigner_price is not :cfp", {cp: nil, cfp: nil}])